# Запрос VIEW в Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Хочу внести новое условие, чтобы идентифицировать людей, которые посетили ресторан. Правильно ли составлено решение для данного условия?

```
CREATE VIEW [People attended] AS
SELECT visitorName, visitorNum
FROM visitor;
```

И как бы я мог доработать его, чтобы я мог выбрать конкретное время посещения и сразу увидеть всех людей которые находились в ресторане, к примеру в 18:00?

Скрипт доступен по ссылке:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/91ab1/1

Comment: +1 за предоставленный SQL fiddle)